# Creating Dynamic Elements inside Div C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to create dynamic elements inside my div on c# asp.net. I need asp:TextBox instead of HTML textbox.
This code works:

```
create.InnerHtml = "<input type='text' name='name' value='first Text'/>";
```

while this does not:

```
create.InnerHtml = "<asp:TextBox runat=\"server\"></asp:TextBox>";
```

Problem is I need **runat="server"**. How to create asp:TextBox dynamically inside div? or HTML Textbox has attr of runat="server"? Thank you.

Comment: are you creating element from code behind ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create [HtmlInputText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputtext(v=vs.110).aspx) control with type `text` and add it in `div` `Controls` collection.

```
HtmlInputText text1 = new HtmlInputText("text");
text1.Name = "name";
text1.Value = "first Text";
create.Controls.Add(text1);
```

Comment: can HTML textboxes have runat="server" attributes?

Comment: If you create and add HtmlInputText as I did you would not require runat Server. They can have but you have to add them in HTML like <input id="id1" runat="server" />

Comment: I cannot. because I am creating it dynamically.

Comment: Adding HtmlInputText as shown will do the same as runat server would do, Is anything you think could not be done with this?

Answer (score 0):

I tested if HTML TextBox can have runat="server" attribute, it does!
This code works.

```
create.InnerHtml = "<input type='text' name='name' runat=\"server\" value='first Text'/>";
```